# How to Billing of SIP call session when concurrent call make

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I am making Billing server for Conference calls. I am using Asterisk and A2Billing. All things work when Single Calling Card make call. But when Single Calling Card make concurrent calls then Billing server don't perform well due to A2Biling programming. 
When call was generated from a2biling then A2B check credit and then after testing with Tariiffplan convert into nen0seconds. So don't check that we are making Single call or making another call from that card.

So if anyone know how to make real-time billing with asterisk server then please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

In that case, it might be best to use a billing system able to do real time billing. NibbleBill is a billing system available for Freeswitch and it can do it. A2Billing will not cut it for you because it does things differently by checking the account balance only at the beginning of the call and updating the account balance at the en of the call. Let's make the following assumptions:

- The account's credit is $10
- The average session time of 5 minutes
- There are 10 participants in the conference

The following WILL happen:

- If all the participants get connected in less than 5 minutes (the average session duration), then they will all hear (if audio where activated): You have 10$
- At the end of the call, each participant will potential consume a maximum of 10$
- If all the participant use up the $10, the final account balance will be a big fat negative -$90 which is the initial $10 minute  $10 x 10 participants ($100).

A real real-time billing system will have a daemon running in the background and monitoring the lines. It will be able to disconnect any call when the total credit used by all the instances of a given account reaches ~0.